# Oracle Full Client / Database Client package locations

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, export, expdp

I need to install multiple versions of the Oracle client on an app server for an automation project. The platform I'm looking for in specific is Linux, 64 bit.

Oracle's network of websites are a maze and not helpful at all.

Here is what I've found:

12.1.0.1 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-linux-download-1959253.html

11.2.0.1 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html

11.2.0.4 : ??? Who knows, but luckily we have a copy on our repo servers at work.

I need to find the package for 11.2.0.2.

The reason I'm not just using a 12c client for everything (as much as I would like to) is because I can't. This annoying error greets you trying to use **expdp** a 11.2.0.2 database using the 12c client:

> Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Feb 24 14:14:39 2015
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved. UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database
>   version 11.2.0.2.0

So much for backwards compatibility.

P.S., the source database is a production 11.2.0.2 database that will not be upgraded for at least a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to software downloads for production use, the Oracle sites, thankfully, are a little less of a maze - provided that you are familiar with the entrance.

You can find the latest media packs for production use on the [Oracle Software Delivery Cloud](https://edelivery.oracle.com).

After logging in and accepting terms and export restrictions, select **Oracle Database** and **Linux x86-64**. After hitting **Go**, you should be able to find **Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0) Media Pack for Linux x86-64** and within; the **Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Linux x86-64**.

You can find **Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) Media Pack for Linux x86-64** and the associated **Oracle Database 12c Release 1 Client (12.1.0.2.0) for Linux x86-64 (64-bit)** in much the same way.

The patch from 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.2.0 should be downloaded from Metalink / [My Oracle Support](http://support.oracle.com).

Starting with 11.2.0.2.0, any subsequent updates can be downloaded from with the installer itself, either as an integrated part of the installation process, or in advance (useful when destined server is restricted from accessing the Internet) by running the installer with the option `-downloadUpdates`.

I guess you have already considered just running the datapump tools from the actual Oracle home of the database in question?

These days, you may also be offered to try out a new and enhanced version of the software delivery cloud. Look for a big link on the landing page/login page.

On a final note, lots of additional information can be found in the Client Installation Guides available in the [Oracle Database Online Documentation 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_11.htm) or [Oracle Database Online Documentation 12c Release 1 (12.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/nav/portal_11.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the information. We have ruled out running the datapump tools from the actual oracle home because that would involve configuring ssh access from our automation server to all of the target database servers.

So you are saying that the 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2 patch is not public, correct? That blows my mind. In any case, I've tried looking in Oracle Support for the upgrade patch but I could not find the link.

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan   Open a SR and ask for the patch. They'll provide it.

Comment: AFAIK all patches require access to My Oracle Support, even when downloading them from within the installer. Specific versions are available on OTN, but I don't think I have seen any patches.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone *is* looking for 11.2.0.4, go to this link https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=13390677

and download Oracle client (11.2.0.4) 64-bit which is  `p13390677_112040_platform_4of7.zip`

For 32-bit you need to download `p13390677_112040_platform_3of6.zip`

Comment: While this was not the OP's question (they had 11.2.0.4 covered), it may be helpful in providing a link to the one version listed that didn't have one.